# Selecting features from multiple layers for export QGIS 3.6

Tags: qgis, layers, features, select

I have multiple features I want to select over multiple layers and then export these selected features to a new layer.

The 'Multiple Layer Selection' plugin is not supported by the QGIS 3.6 so that is not an option.

I know I can create one massive layer file and use expressions to display and then select only the features I want but this is a cumbersome process compared to being able to use the default (rectangle) select tool across multiply layers.

Is there potentially a way to use the identify feature tool to create an attribute table that contains all the identified features across all layers? That would add an extra step to the selection process but is still better than using multiple expressions on a massive layer file.

Comment: Do you want to select by point or rectangle?

Comment: I'm working on Multiple Layer Selection to upgrade it to QGIS 3. It's already working, but I trying to solve a problem related to the upgrade.

Comment: I would like to select the features by rectangle (so the default select feature option)

Comment: Ok, If you like, you can test my upgrade. See my answer. Tell me if you see any problems.

Comment: You want to draw one rectangle and get a selection in multiple layers for that one rectangle?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on Multiple Layer Selection to upgrade it to QGIS 3. It's already working, but I trying to solve a problem related to the upgrade. Feel free to try it. You can download it [here](https://github.com/felferrari/MultipleLayerSelection/tree/qgis3).

Comment: Brilliant...now do you happen to have it as an install-able zip? I am new to QGIS and my level of expertise around installing packages is using the plugin install feature built into QGIS.

Comment: I am wondering whether "Merge Vector Layers" is not the same as append in QGIS?

Comment: Broken Link and Plugin still not complete in 2020.

Comment: We've just submitted the new version to QGIS. We're waiting for approval.

Comment: Version 2.0 for QGIS 3.x is now approved!

Answer (score 1):

I recently developped a [small plugin for QGIS3](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/multilayerselect) that adds a toolbar with a "multilayer" version of the QGIS selection tools. You can also optionaly replace the default tools with the custom ones.

[image: toolbar]

**Note**: While I was developing it, the QGIS3 version of the original plugin was submitted and approved (thanks to [lcoandrade](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/61682/lcoandrade)). I encourage you to give both a try :)